# Iterating through keys in JSON C#

Tags: c#, json, api, web

I have a JSON file which looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "appid": 620,
    "playtime_forever": 841,
    "playtime_windows_forever": 841,
    "playtime_mac_forever": 0,
    "playtime_linux_forever": 0,
    "rtime_last_played": 1639764755
  },
  {
    "appid": 105600,
    "playtime_2weeks": 21,
    "playtime_forever": 25522,
    "playtime_windows_forever": 25521,
    "playtime_mac_forever": 0,
    "playtime_linux_forever": 0,
    "rtime_last_played": 1664472469
  },
  {
    "appid": 211050,
    "playtime_forever": 0,
    "playtime_windows_forever": 0,
    "playtime_mac_forever": 0,
    "playtime_linux_forever": 0,
    "rtime_last_played": 0
  },
```

It's only a small portion of it. It's a web response from Steam API about owned games from a user. Each game contains a key "playtime_forever". It stores minutes of playtime in a game which I want to get FOR EACH GAME, sum and write it to the console. Until now I got this:

```cs
        public const string APIKey = ProtectedAPIKey.APIKey;

        public const string SteamGamesAPILink = $"https://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v1?key={APIKey}&steamid=76561198871868188";
        public const string SteamLevelAPILink = $"https://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetSteamLevel/v1?key={APIKey}&steamid=76561198871868188";

        static WebClient wc = new();

        public static void Main()
        {

            byte[] SteamGamesAPIResponse = wc.DownloadData(SteamGamesAPILink);
            byte[] SteamLevelAPIResponse = wc.DownloadData(SteamLevelAPILink);


            string SteamLevelAPIResponseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(SteamLevelAPIResponse);
            string SteamGamesAPIResponseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(SteamGamesAPIResponse);

            var levelRoot = JToken.Parse(SteamLevelAPIResponseString);
            var gamesRoot = JToken.Parse(SteamGamesAPIResponseString);

#pragma warning disable CS8604
            var playtime = gamesRoot
                .SelectToken("response")
                .SelectToken("games");
                //no idea what to do next...
#pragma warning restore CS8604

            var level = levelRoot
                .SelectToken("response")
                .SelectToken("player_level");

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.WriteLine($"Player level: {level}");
        }
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow rudynakodach! have you ever thought to just parse them into a list of POCO? i mean, make a class with fields to store those value then deserialize it into that class. you can then use [tag:linq] to aggregate stuffs. less headache, easier to read.

Comment: also, that json parser, is it [tag:json.net] (often known as `Newtonsoft.Json`) or .net core one?

Comment: That's Newtonsoft.

Comment: What is a "list of POCO"?

Comment: make a class with properties such as `appid`, `playtime_forever`, etc. then use `JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<myClass>>(the-json-text)`, see [the docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm). you can then able to leverage [tag:linq].

Comment: @BagusTesa I think at this point you can collect all your suggestions and create an answer from it :)

Answer (score 0):

you can put all your code in one line using Linq

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

int playTimeForEverSum = JArray.Parse(json).Sum(ja => (int) ja["playtime_forever"]);
```